# PHP use page name as variable

Tags: php

What I would like to do is say someone comes to my site and goes to

`www.site.com/users/james`

The page `/james` won't exist so I want to take the name `james` and use it to then display a profile page based on that user name i.e use `james` in a search to pull back info from my DB.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: .htaccess rewrite is what you want.
index.php?user=james to go to /users/james

Comment: nice, you are getting into routing here, many frameworks would use something like this `/<controller>/<method>/<params>` so what you may want to do is build a simple router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/users/(.+?) /users.php?name=$1
```

**users.php**

```
<?php
if ($_GET['name']) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
         $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
         print_r($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, I have my .htaccess in the root of my mamp folder with 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.+?) /profile.php?name=$1

but when I go to site/profile/james I'm unable to get james as a $_GET, any clues?

Comment: try $_REQUEST['name']

Comment: That didn't work but I have managed to find some info on it now I know what I need to loog for thanks :)